# STIDF time interval

Tags: r, spatial, xts

I m trying to convert a spatial point data into STI

`c2168.st <- STIDF(sp, time = c2168$date, data = c2168[,c("id","date")]) 
Warning message: In STI(sp, time) : STI(): setting timeIsInterval to default value FALSE.`
How should I set it ? 
I used 
`timeIsInterval(time) = "FALSE"` , prio to STIDF but without succes.
Thanks
B.